# Error in SQL syntax when update a Blob from java

Tags: java, mysql

```
public static Boolean userImage(String userIdString, InputStream stream) {

        PreparedStatement statement = null;    
        String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE `users` SET `image` = ? WHERE `id` = ? ;";

        try {

            Integer userId = Integer.parseInt(userIdString);    
            statement = DatabaseManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);    
            statement.setBinaryStream(1, stream);
            statement.setInt(2, userId);                
            Log.write("USER IMAGE UPDATED> " + statement);              
            statement.executeUpdate(updateTableSQL);                

            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.write("USER IMAGE UPDATED> " + e.getMessage());    
            return false;

        } finally {

            if (statement != null) {
                try {
                    statement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Log:

> 09:55:59:0496: USER IMAGE UPDATED>
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@1c902d70: UPDATE `users` SET
>   `image` = ** STREAM DATA ** WHERE `id` = 29 ;
>
> 09:55:59:0511: USER IMAGE UPDATED> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '? WHERE `id` = 29' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of `executeUpdate`

As you have already created a statement with parameters

change `statement.executeUpdate(updateTableSQL);` to `statement.executeUpdate();`